# Python/Pandas – Como retirar espaço a mais entre duas palavras de uma coluna do data frame

Tags: python, pandas

A função “strip” retira os espaços a esquerda e direita, mas não retira os espaços entre as palavras:

```
raw_data = {'NAME': ['   José  Luiz   da   Silva   ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['NAME'])
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
rdata = {'NAME': ['   José           Luiz   da       Silva   ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(rdata, columns = ['NAME'])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
  df.set_value(i,'NAME',' '.join(row.NAME.split()))

print (df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 NAME
0  José Luiz da Silva
```

[Execute no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JN3a/5)