# Agrupar por semana

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho uma tabela igual esta  estou tentando separar por semana, não tenho muito conhecimento em quais funções posso usar para verificar quantas semanas tem entre essas datas, para depois agrupar. Os dados estão em uma tabela csv, estou usando pandas para abrir o arquivo csv.

```
         Nome completo  count
Hora                                                      

2017-03-06  Talita       4
2017-03-07  Filho        8
2017-03-07  Jao         10
2017-03-07  Otavio       6
2017-03-08  Gabriel      2
2017-03-13  Guilherme    1
```

Tabela final que eu pretendo montar

```
Nome         Semana_1  Semana_2   
Talita          4         0
Filho           8         0
Jao             10        0
Otavio          6         0
Gabriel         2         0
Guilherme       0         1
```

Comment: O que seria agrupar por semanas? Por quê é necessário verificar quantas semanas há entre as datas? De onde vem essa tabela?

Comment: Agrupar quando count o nome teve na semana daquela data.. Eu tinha pensando em verificar quantas semanas tem entre o dia 06 o dia 08   exemplo pra uma data maior teria 7 semanas com isso eu vou verificar essa data 2017-03-06 pertence na primeira semana então vou colocar na primeira semana talita teve 4 count.. Sobre a tabela eu montei pra aprender agrupar por semana esses dados. Desculpa não ter mt informação

Comment: Pode ser eu, e se for, desculpe-me, mas simplesmente não consegui entender o que você disse. "*Agrupar quando count o nome teve na semana daquela data*", essa frase não pareceu fazer sentido; "*verificar quantas semanas tem entre o dia 06 o dia 08 exemplo pra uma data maior teria 7 semanas*", quê? Entre 06 e 08 há 1 dia apenas e o que seria essa data maior? Tem como colocar um [mcve]? Principalmente com datas que possuam semanas de diferença, não apenas datas próximas.

Comment: Me desculpa, mas coloquei um exemplo do final q eu estou tentando montar.

Comment: E como estão estruturados esses dados no Python? Coloque isso na pergunta também.

Comment: Matheus, você precisa colaborar dando as informações necessárias. Dizer que os dados estão em um CSV é inútil sem os dados em si. Coloque **exatamente** como os dados estão e já coloque o código Python que você está utilizando para ler esses dados. Seja objetivo e claro na pergunta. Informações são triviais para resolver o problema, não as omita.

Comment: não tem muito código, tem apenas uma linha indicando que estou abrindo o arquivo csv  log_df = pd.read_csv('logs/logs.csv',delimiter=","), os dados estão exatamente deste jeito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que vc está usando o pandas para ler o `csv`, sugiro utilizar suas próprias funções para resolver essa questão. Com certeza deve haver várias maneiras de fazer isso com o pandas, vou apresentar a que me ocorreu.

> Editado
>   Veja que vou repetir `Talita`, na mesma semana, para mostrar e eficácia da solução. :-)

Simulando o `csv`:

```
import io 
import pandas as pd

s = '''
"Data","Nome","Count"
2017-03-06,"Talita",4
2017-03-07,"Filho",8
2017-03-07,"Jao",10
2017-03-07,"Talita",5
2017-03-07,"Otavio",6
2017-03-08,"Gabriel",2
2017-03-13,"Guilherme",1
'''
```

Lendo o `csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), parse_dates=True)
```

Fazendo o agrupamento:

```
df['Data']=pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])
df['Semana'] = df['Data'].dt.to_period('W-THU')
df = df.groupby(by=['Semana', 'Nome'])['Nome', 'Count', 'Data'].sum()
```

Resultado final:

```
                                 Count
Semana                Nome            
2017-03-03/2017-03-09 Filho          8
                      Gabriel        2
                      Jao           10
                      Otavio         6
                      Talita         9
2017-03-10/2017-03-16 Guilherme      1
```

​A partir dessa tabela vc pode fazer um `iterrows` montar no formato que desejar, além de poder exportar para varios formatos com o `.to`, como por exemplo: `df.to_csv`, `df.to_json`, `to_latex, to_pickle, to_records, to_string, to_xarray` e  "por ai vai...."

Comment: Muito obrigado achei muito bom mesmo sua solução, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Opa, bom saber que ajudou, considere dar o aceite na questão (sinal proximo da seta de votação) :-)

Comment: só uma ultima duvida para eu montar a tabela que eu desejo com iterrows, poderia dar uma ajuda na lógica?

Comment: Dá um olhada [nessa resposta,](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217954/7412) que tem essa lógica, aproveita e dá um voto. :-)

Comment: Voce pode, tb, converter para um dicionário com `df.to_dict()` e montar a partir dele.

Answer (score 1):

Matheus, eu montei um código onde eu crio um dicionário com os dados que voce passou ai, e crio 2 metodos: um para adicionar a semana exata do ano em cada objeto da lista de usuários, outro para organizar a tabela de saída, para estar o mais proximo possivel do que voce quer montar ai em seu exemplo.

Para identificar a semana, eu usei o atributo [.isocalendar()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar), que retorna uma tupla contendo o calendário da semana.

```
import datetime

user_list = [
    {
        "name": "Talita",
        "count": 4,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=6),
    },
    {
        "name": "Filho",
        "count": 8,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=7),
    },
    {
        "name": "Jao",
        "count": 10,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=7),
    },
    {
        "name": "Otavio",
        "count": 6,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=7),
    },
    {
        "name": "Gabriel",
        "count": 2,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=8),
    },
    {
        "name": "Guilherme",
        "count": 1,
        "date": datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=13),
    },
]

def get_week(user_list):
    for u in user_list:
        week = u['date'].isocalendar()[1]
        u['week'] = week
    return user_list

def group_by_week(user_list):
    actual_week = 0
    week_group = {}
    for u in user_list:
        if actual_week != u['week']:
            week_group[u['week']] = []
            week_group[u['week']].append(u)
            actual_week = u['week']
        else:
            week_group[actual_week].append(u)
    return week_group


# Adicionando semana em cada objeto
print("~> Adicionando semana em cada objeto e printando")
user_list = get_week(user_list)
for t in user_list:
    print("Name: %s, week: %s" % (t['name'], t['week']))

print("\n~> Organizando tabela de saida")
# Organizando tabela
week_group = group_by_week(user_list)
count_week = 0
for key in week_group:
    if count_week < key:
        count_week += 1
    print("# Semana %s" % count_week)
    for user in week_group[key]:
        print("Name: %s, count: %s, date: %s" % (user['name'], user['count'], user['date']))
```

**Resultado**

```
~> Adicionando semana em cada objeto e printando
Name: Talita, week: 10
Name: Filho, week: 10
Name: Jao, week: 10
Name: Otavio, week: 10
Name: Gabriel, week: 10
Name: Guilherme, week: 11

~> Organizando tabela de saida
# Semana 1
Name: Talita, count: 4, date: 2017-03-06
Name: Filho, count: 8, date: 2017-03-07
Name: Jao, count: 10, date: 2017-03-07
Name: Otavio, count: 6, date: 2017-03-07
Name: Gabriel, count: 2, date: 2017-03-08
# Semana 2
Name: Guilherme, count: 1, date: 2017-03-13
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, sua resposta me ajudou bastante, mas me surgiu uma duvida se eu tiver na mesma semana o mesmo usuário e queira só agrupar o count no nome afinal  é a mesma pessoa?

Comment: Ai voce vai ter que fazer mais uma funcaozinha para unificar duplicidades. Voce pode usar o reduce, como no exemplo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078694/returning-sum-of-duplicate-elements-in-javascript-array