# Montando tabela a partir de um csv, agrupada por semana, com python e pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou usando pandas e abro a seguinte tabela usando o código

```
tst = pd.read_csv('Iteracao.csv',delimiter=",")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando agrupar da seguinte forma, onde week 1 é a semana da data 2017-02-10/2017-02-16,  seguindo a lógica para as outras semana, o indice não precisa ser week, pode ser a data mas estou tentando agrupar assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tentativa  foi a usando a seguinte logica, eu salvo em uma coluna

```
semana = df['Semana'].dt.to_period('W-THU')
semana = np.unique(semana)
```

e pego só uma vez cada valor depois eu ia tentar percorrer um for de iterrows para verificar se a semana(i) igual a linha da coluna Semana row['Semana'] dps tentar salvar em outra tabela.

```
for index, row in tst.iterrows():
    for i in range(s):      
        n = semana[i]
        if row['Semana'] == n :
            print('1')
            tp['Nome']=row['Nome completo']
            tp['count']=row['count']
            print(tp)
```

a resposta não precisa ser código mas apenas lógica para eu seguir.
Obrigado

Comment: Coloque os dados ao invés de imagens, fica mais fácil para quem quiser tentar ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://anaconda.org/sidon/grp-pandas-weeks/notebook)
Percebi que vc ja [aplicou essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230516/7412), e exportou a tabela resultante para um `csv` e agora quer montar a tabela final a partir da leitura dele, certo?
Como voce deixou imagens e não dados nessa pergunta, vou usar os dados [daquela resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230516/7412), (exportados para o `csv` de nome `test1.csv`) para apresentar a solução. Juro que tentei atender seu pedido de não colocar o código e sim uma explicação, mas chegou no final nem eu mesmo conseguia entender e, fui implementar para ver e acabei fazendo tudo diferente :-). Então vou responder com codigo mesmo.

Leitura do arquivo:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

# Lendo o arquivo para uma lista de linhas
f = open('test1.csv', mode='r')
lines = f.readlines()

# Exculuindo o cabeçalho
del lines[0]
```

Resultado inicial:

```
lines
['2017-03-03/2017-03-09,Filho,8\n',
 '2017-03-03/2017-03-09,Gabriel,2\n',
 '2017-03-03/2017-03-09,Jao,10\n',
 '2017-03-03/2017-03-09,Otavio,6\n',
 '2017-03-03/2017-03-09,Talita,9\n',
 '2017-03-10/2017-03-16,Guilherme,1\n',
 '2017-03-10/2017-03-16,Talita,7\n']
```

Criando o dicionário e variaveis auxiliares

```
semanas, nomes = [], []
d1 = OrderedDict()
for l in lines:
    line = l.rstrip().split(',')
    if line[0] not in semanas:
        semanas.append(line[0])
        d1[line[0]] = {}
    d1[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2]

nomes=[]
[nomes.append(k) for v in d1.values() for k in v.keys() if k not in nomes]
```

Tabulando os dados para alimentar o dataframe

```
data = [] 
for nome in nomes:
    n = []
    for semana in semanas:
        if nome in d1[semana]:
            n.append(d1[semana][nome])
        else:
            n.append(0)
    data.append(n)
```

Resutado intermediário (dicionário, nomes, semanas e dados):

```
d1
{'2017-03-03/2017-03-09': {'Filho': '8',
  'Gabriel': '2',
  'Jao': '10',
  'Otavio': '6',
  'Talita': '9'},
 '2017-03-10/2017-03-16': {'Guilherme': '1', 'Talita': '7'}}

nomes
['Filho', 'Gabriel', 'Jao', 'Otavio', 'Talita', 'Guilherme']

semanas
['2017-03-03/2017-03-09', '2017-03-10/2017-03-16']

data
[['8', 0], ['2', 0], ['10', 0], ['6', 0], ['9', '7'], [0, '1']]
```

Construindo e formatando a tabela final.

```
columns = []
for i in range(len(semanas)):
    columns.append('Week'+str(i))    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=nomes, columns=columns)
```

Resultado final (imagem):
[image: Resultado final]

Se quiser pode nomear o indice, geralmente não faço porque cria uma linha em branco somente para a nomeação, ao invés de aporveitar o espaço em branco da coluna dos indices, ainda nao consegui isso.

[Veja a execução do codigo em um Jupyter Notebook, aqui.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/grp-pandas-weeks/notebook)